# What is the ExifTool syntax to extract thumbnails from raw to a specific folder?

Tags: exiftool

My source folders are on an external hard drive, but I want my thumbnails local. The following works, but it puts all the extracted files in the same folder as the source files, which requires another step to collect them and move them to a folder on my local machine.

```
exiftool -b -ThumbnailImage -w _thumb.jpg -ext CR2 -r source_folder_path\ > _extraction_results.txt
```

Is there any way to write them to a different folder in the same call to ExifTool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the directory path to name given in the [`-w` (textout) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#w-EXT-or-FMT--textOut) (see examples at that link).

Example:
`exiftool -b -ThumbnailImage -w /path/to/thumbdir/%f_thumb.jpg -ext CR2 -r source_folder_path\ > _extraction_results.txt`

Comment: I'm still having an issue with the syntax. hate to be so dense.

Using your example and substituting my /path/to/thumbdir/ I get "Error creating ..."

Exiftool is appending my target folder path to the source_folder_path which produces an invalid (and incorrect) file path. What am I missing?

Also: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Oops, my mistake for not testing it out before.  Unless one of the special variables is used (`%d`, `%f`, `%c`, or `%e`) the argument following the `-w` option gets appended to the filename.  In the above change, it now writes to the path, then has the filename without extension (the `%f`), then the `_thumb.jpg`.  See the link for the explanation of the % codes.

Comment: That's the trick! Now that I have it working, I think I can get a better handle on using the other variables. Thanks!